# Mix Sort order Android SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a Table ProductTable in which products are listed by 3 types

product_Name, product_Type and product_Year

Lets say i have 10 products

```
A - 2014 , 2015
B - 2014 , 2015
C - 2014 , 2015
D - 2014 , 2015
E - 2014 , 2015

Product A B C are of type 1 and D and E are of type 2

When i sort using year desc i get 2015 products and then 2014 products(expected behaviour)

when i sort using name and year desc i get A 2015, A2014, B2015, B2014 and so on (expected behaviour)

When i sort using type i get 
B 2014 ,
B 2015 ,
C 2014 ,
C 2015 ,
A 2014 ,
A 2015 ,
E 2014 ,
E 2015 ,
D 2014 ,
D 2015 .
```

the query i use for sorting is

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE productActive=? ORDER BY product_type
```

Required scenario is I want same order as above  (B,C,A,E,D) but the 2015 product should come before the 2014

```
eg.  B 2015 ,
B 2014 ,
C 2015 ,
C 2014 ,
A 2015 ,
A 2014 ,
E 2015 ,
E 2014 ,
D 2015 ,
D 2014 .
```

i Tried to use group by year or name but that is not giving the desired result.

Also tried adding `product_year DESC` but it was giving all 2015 first and then 2014 .

Any Inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do "ORDER BY type" you are telling SQlite to return all rows with a type of 1, followed by all rows with a type of 2. Within each of these two groups you are however not specifying any order, which means the order is undefined.

From SQLite specification:

"If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined"

Granted, you do have an ORDER BY clause, but only on one level so once items are grouped by type the internal order will be undefined.

I am not aware of any way to accomplish what you want since you rely on an implicit undefined order to be used before your specified order.

Why do you need items in this seemingly random order?

Comment: `ORDER BY 
  CASE ID
    WHEN 2015 THEN 1
    WHEN 2014 THEN 2
  END` Can this be used if it helps ?

Comment: Hmm, what is ID in this case? Your primary key? I suspect that the mentioned "undefined" order *could* be ordering by primary key, but it's not very safe to rely on such implicit ordering. But in your clause above you seem to be expecting "ID" to have values 2014, 2015 etc, isn't that the "year" column?

Comment: In general, when posting questions like this, it help *a lot* if you actually include your table schema with all columns, primary keys, constraints etc (basically your CREATE TABLE statement).
If in fact SQLite uses primary key as the implicit default order (and you do have a primary key), you might be able to accomplish what you want by using 

ORDER BY product_type ASC, ID asc, year DESC

Comment: sorry my mistake i should have mentioned ID is product year   `ORDER BY CASE PRODUCT_YEAR WHEN 2015 THEN 1 WHEN 2014 THEN 2 END` can this be of any help

Comment: my primary key is a mix of 2 values that is productyear_productversion  
PRIMARY_KEY +" (" + FeedEntry.product_id + COMMA + FeedEntry.version_id + "))";  now that you said so i think we might be near Lemme have a look how can i use this

Comment: I don't think that will work regardless. And my idea with adding your primary key (if there is one) won't work either, because since no keys are the same this order will make ordering by year after id pointless.
Please post your entire create table statement to make it clearer what kind of data we have here and I might be able to help more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71756/discussion-between-backstabber-and-jhh).